# VTK Requested modules not available vtkIOFFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, vtk

Im try to execute this [example](https://lorensen.github.io/VTKExamples/site/Cxx/Video/FFMPEG/) from VTK, and to do that I most install ffmpeg from this [url](https://vtk.org/download/) and all is good, but when I try to build project I get this error:

> /Downloads/VTK-8.2.0/CMake/vtkModuleAPI.cmake:140 (message):
>   Requested modules not available:
>
> ```
> vtkIOFFMPEG
> ```

I do all step in ffmpeg zipped file which I installed it from VTK download [url](https://vtk.org/download/), and if press ccmake on **VTK-build** directory I can see these option is enabled

> VTK_FFMPEG_INCLUDE_DIR           /tmp/ffmpeg_inst/include
>   VTK_FFMPEG_avcodec_LIBRARY       /tmp/ffmpeg_inst/lib/libavcodec.so
>   VTK_FFMPEG_avformat_LIBRARY      /tmp/ffmpeg_inst/lib/libavformat.so
>   VTK_FFMPEG_avutil_LIBRARY        /tmp/ffmpeg_inst/lib/libavutil.so
>   VTK_USE_FFMPEG_ENCODER           ON

and all files/directory is found and located under /tmp/ffmpeg_inst,
Also I run make -j4 after VTK_USE_FFMPEG_ENCODER is set on.

Why vtkIOFFMPEG module not found now? is there any mistake in configuration or is there any specific configuration for FFMPEG example before build? thanks.

Additional Note:

1. VTK version: 8.2.0
2. cmake version 3.13.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an answer for this question, Simply its by go to VTK-build directory, and then set `Module_vtkIOFFMPEG = ON` then rebuild.

Also in this version You need to set path like this:

```
 FFMPEG_LIBAVCODEC_INCLUDE_DIRS   /ffmpeg_inst/include                                                                           
 FFMPEG_LIBAVCODEC_LIBRARIES      /ffmpeg_inst/lib/libavcodec.so                                                                 
 FFMPEG_LIBAVDEVICE_INCLUDE_DIR   /ffmpeg_inst/include                                                                           
 FFMPEG_LIBAVDEVICE_LIBRARIES     /ffmpeg_inst/lib/libavdevice.so                                                                
 FFMPEG_LIBAVFORMAT_INCLUDE_DIR   /ffmpeg_inst/include                                                                           
 FFMPEG_LIBAVFORMAT_LIBRARIES     /ffmpeg_inst/lib/libavformat.so                                                                
 FFMPEG_LIBAVUTIL_INCLUDE_DIRS    /ffmpeg_inst/include                                                                           
 FFMPEG_LIBAVUTIL_LIBRARIES       /ffmpeg_inst/lib/libavutil.so                                                                  
 FFMPEG_LIBSWRESAMPLE_INCLUDE_D   /ffmpeg_inst/include                                                                           
 FFMPEG_LIBSWRESAMPLE_LIBRARIES   /ffmpeg_inst/lib/libswresample.so                                                              
 FFMPEG_LIBSWSCALE_INCLUDE_DIRS   /ffmpeg_inst/include                                                                           
 FFMPEG_LIBSWSCALE_LIBRARIES      /ffmpeg_inst/lib/libswscale.so
```

Good luck all.